# Crashresistent and performant key-value store which can be installed and used by our software

Tags: performance, key-value-store

We have a product where we have a server running as a windows service which used a very old database called QDBM. It is quite fast, but as soon as our service crashes or so the database is corrupt.

We are searching now for a replacement for this. We don't need a complex database, but it should be possible to just deliver it with our software and install everything automatically. It should be able to store several million keys and corresponding values (from 50 byte up to several hundred bytes per entry) and performant.

Some of the information we always hold in the memory, so it would be great if we could retrieve that quite fast. And up to 2000 clients can send data to us once per second which means that we need to update (most of the time the same) 2000 entries in the database.

We don't need transactions and it is ok if some of the latest information is lost, as we discover the latest data in the background and after a while this will be repaired.

I tried already leveldb which is ok from performance perspective, but it seems to hang after some hours. Maybe internal reorganizations or so, this was already reported by others.

Mongodb was 50 times slower, I don't know why. My test just drops the database, creates 100k entries and reads them which takes 21 seconds while the same took 0.4 seconds with leveldb.

Redis sounds like a good solution, but I have problems to find a free still supported windows version (memurai seems to cost something)? Most people propose to install it under Windows' linux shell, but I think this sounds more like a solution if you have a single database server, but not if you want to deliver a software which should run on hundreds of computers.

As I said, maybe a simpler solution would be sufficient for us.

BTW: It would be nice if the database can be synched to another computer (we have a failover service), but thats not a must.

It would be really great if you have more proposals.

Comment: Did you find the solution?